# When I include git2.h from libgit2, I can access data structures, but not functions

Tags: c, libgit2

Here is some code from Ben Straub's (link blog) that I am basing this on:

```
static int do_clone(const char *url, const char *path)
{
    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    int ret = git_clone(&repo, url, path, NULL);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    return ret;
}
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <git2.h>

int main(void) {
        git_repository *out = NULL;

        git_clone(&out, "https://github.com/lehitoskin/racketball", "/home/maxwell", NULL);

        return 0;
}
```

I am very inexperienced with C, so I apologize for having such elementary problems. Anyway, here is the error my compiler gives me:

```
maxwell@max-pc ~ $ gcc -I libgit2/include gitfun.c
/tmp/ccB64nPh.o: In function `main':
gitfun.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `git_clone'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why can't I call git_clone this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you didn't link to the library. Add -lgit2 if libgit2 is the lib name.

```
gcc -I libgit2/include gitfun.c -L<path to lib> -l<libname minus the "lib" part>
```

IOW, you compile fine but when the linker goes looking for `git_clone` it can't find it because you haven't specified the library that it is in.

Comment: You are my hero. I promise I am trying to not suck at C. Thank you so much!